# Poll on an endpoint and create an observable of the result

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an endpoint `/user/?is_active=1` which gives me folowing response

```
{ count: 123,
  next: "next_page_url",
  previous: null,
  results: [
     {id: 323, name: "test"},
     {id: 324, name: "test2"},
     {id: 336, name: "test3"},
     {id: 328, name: "test4"},
  ]
}
```

My target is to show number of active users, and update the data every 60 sec by polling on the endpoint (no socket... for now).
I have a component `TestComponent`, which uses a service `UserService` .

```
@Component {
   selector: 'test',
   pipes: [Async],
   template: `<div>{{totalActiveUsers}}</div>`,
}
export class TestComponent {
   public totalActiveUsers;
   constructor(userService: UserService) {
      userService.activeUser.subscribe(data => {
         this.totalActiveUsers =  data.count;
      })
   }
}
```

`UserService` looks like this

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Users} from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    public acitveUser: Observable<Users> = new Observable()
    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }
    getActiveUser() {
       return this._http.get('/user/?is_active=1').map(res => res.json())
    }
    ...
    //incomplete
}
```

I want to poll the enpoint every 60 sec and `UserService.activeUser` to be an `observable` which I can subscribe to, which gives me the response everytime I have new list of active users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `interval` operator of observables this way:

```
export class TestComponent {
  public totalActiveUsers;
  constructor(userService: UserService) {
    Observable.interval(60000).flatMap(() => {
      return this.service.getActiveUser();
    }).subscribe((activeUsers) => {
      this.totalActiveUsers =  data.count;
    });
  }

  (...)
}
```

Comment: `debounce` can also be used i guess other than `interval`. am I right?

Comment: thanks @thierry, this works. But this code makes the first call after 1 min. Is there a way to execute its once and then keep polling?